# Page Template Dropdown - Missing In WordPress MultiSite

Tags: multisite, page-template

I am using WordPress Multi-Site and on the page edit screen I am completely missing the Page Template drop down.

I have tried looking in Page Options and it's missing from there as well.  If I enable the same theme in standard WordPress then the page templates show up

Anyone any ideas?

Comment: Ain't your theme which doesn't have page templates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved, turns out there was references to BuddyPress is my theme which were causing a conflict

My theme was originally a BuddyPress theme,  I had since ditched BP and was using the theme as a standard WP theme.

Still lingering in the template information file was....

```
Template: bp-default
Tags: buddypress
```

With these tags the theme still functioned but the templates were not being displayed, removed them and everything is fixed

Comment: Can you explain what that conflict was, for the sake of future visitors?